# Project Euler 3

Tags: vb.net, math

I have been trying to solve question 3 on project euler with the following vb code but I do not under stand why it is not working. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

```
Sub Main()
    Dim p As Int64 = 600851475143
    Dim y As Integer

    For i As Int64 = p / 2 To 1 Step -1
        If p Mod i = 0 Then
            y = 0
            For n As Int64 = 1 To Math.Floor(i ^ 0.5) Step 1
                If i Mod n = 0 Then
                    y = y + 1
                End If

            Next
            If y = 0 Then

                Console.WriteLine(i)
                Console.ReadLine()

            End If

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

The question is "The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.

What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?"

Answer (score 3):

```
For n As Int64 = 1 To Math.Floor(i ^ 0.5) Step 1
    If i Mod n = 0 Then
```

You start with `n=1`. Every number divides evenly by 1.

(so `y = y+1` every time, and `If y = 0 Then` can never happen).